How to disable CBC Cipher Suite when making an API call in C# with HttpWebRequest
I'm making an API call as per the below code snippet:
if (ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol.HasFlag(SecurityProtocolType.Tls12) == false)
{
   ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol || SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
}
HttpWebRequest webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(EndPoint);
Token = GetAuthToken();
HttpWebRequest webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(EndPoint);
webRequest.Method = "GET";
webRequest.Accept = "application/vnd.hmrc.1.0+json";
webRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer " + Token);
var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
StreamReader StreamReader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
string responseJson = StreamReader.ReadToEnd();
if (webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
   // process response
}

However, the API host recently stopped accepting CBC Ciphers. How do I adapt the code above to exclude CBC Ciphers? Thanks in advance for your help.
I found a utility called IISCrypto that does this manually via a GUI, but now I'm looking to do it in C#.

What you ask won't solve anything. The client and server negotiate until they find a mutually accepted cipher, so disabling a cipher serves nothing. The hard-coded ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol severely weakens security too, by re-enabling algorithms that have been deprecated for nearly a decade. And that means that servers no  longer use them

What is the actual problem? Which .NET version are you using? It matters. In .NET Core (which includes .NET 5 and up) HttpWebRequest is just a legacy adapter over HttpClient. In all supported .NET Core and .NET Framework versions TLS/HTTPS is handled by the OS, and the best available options are used automatically. That means TLS 1.3 if available, with fallback to TLS 1.2

.NET Framework 4.7

So what's the actual problem? As long as you run on a supported Windows version (Windows 10 and later), TLS 1.2 or better are used automatically. Remove the attempt to modify SecurityProtocol and try again. Do you get an exception? If so, post the full exception text (ie including inner exceptions). If you run on an unsupported Windows version you may have to patch it.

Some of our customers are running on legacy servers (2008, 2012).
WebException.Message: "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."
WebException.Status: SecureChannelFailure {10} System.Net.WebExceptionStatus

In that case they have to patch them, otherwise TLS 1.2 won't work. TLS is provided by Windows, not .NET. That was thoroughly documented in the 2016-2020 timeframe, when everyone switched to TLS 1.2. There are several old SO questions about this too.

Check the Windows support article on TLS 1.2

Are you sure setting the protocol works? Shouldn't it be like (one pipe symbol): ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; as  shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286086/default-securityprotocol-in-net-4-5 (that still doesn't guarantee client and server will find matching ciphers)
