The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel exception calling openai api from windows 2012 R2 server
In a C# DOTNET 4.8 ASP.NET MVC 5 project running on a Windows 2012 R2 server, I call OpenAi API (v1/chat/completions) using the RestSharp.RestClient like this:
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

var client = new RestClient("[link to openai]");
var request = new RestRequest { Method = Method.Post };
request.AddParameter("application/json", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {OpenAiApiKey}");

var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
return response.Content;

On my localhost (Windows 10), response.Content contains what I expect, with no errors.
On the production machine, the response contains the exception: “The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.” (The call worked on the server not long ago).
ChatGPT suggests to enable TLS 1.2 in the registry:
Enable TLS 1.2 explicitly on the server > modify the registry settings:

Navigate to the following registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols
Create a new key under "Protocols" called "TLS 1.2" if it doesn't already exist.
Under the "TLS 1.2" key, create a new key called "Client".
Under the "Client" key, create a new DWORD value called "DisabledByDefault" and set its value to 0.
Under the "Client" key, create a new DWORD value called "Enabled" and set its value to 1.
Restart the server for the changes to take effect.

Does the ChatGPT suggestion check out?
What am I missing?
/Morten
This is what the Internet options look like:

According to this post (Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel from .NET C#) one problem could be missing cipher suites as listed in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers
I'm unsure how to interpret the ssllabs.com analysis vis-a-vis the server's cipher suites.

I ran this powershell code (from this thread: Default SecurityProtocol in .NET 4.5):
$runtimeVersion = [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo([System.Int32].Assembly.Location).ProductVersion
Write-Host "Runtime: $runtimeVersion"

$enabledProtocols = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol
Write-Host "Enabled protocols: $enabledProtocols"

Write-Host "Available protocols: "
$platformSupportsTls12 = $false
foreach ($protocol in [Enum]::GetValues([System.Net.SecurityProtocolType])) {
    $protocolValue = [int]$protocol
    Write-Host $protocolValue
    if ($protocolValue -eq 3072) {
        $platformSupportsTls12 = $true
    }
}

$isTls12Enabled = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol.HasFlag([System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12)
Write-Host "Is Tls12 enabled: $isTls12Enabled"

And the results were:
Runtime: 4.8.4645.0
Enabled protocols: Ssl3, Tls
Available protocols:
0
48
192
768
3072
12288
Is Tls12 enabled: False
So it seems I must enable Tls12 on the server (looking into the ways to enable thishttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286086/default-securityprotocol-in-net-4-5/28333370#28333370) ...
IIS Crypto 3.3 results appear to allow TLS12, which runs counter to the powershell result:
$isTls12Enabled = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol.HasFlag([System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12)
$isTls12Enabled = False
Not sure what to make of this...

Both Internet Explorer 11 and Firefox appear to be able to communicate via TLS12. Internet Explorer appears also to support TLS10 and TLS11:



that isn't windows server 2003! that looks like 2012 at least

@DanielA.White, you are right. It's a Windows 2012 R2. I have corrected the mistake

Server 2012 R2 reached end of life in October 2023. Are there any plans for your server to be updated soon? Also, this OpenAI forum page seems to say that only TLS 1.3 has been supported since, at the latest, March 2023, and Server 2012 R2 doesn't do TLS 1.3.

Also, get independent confirmation of what ChatGPT says before doing anything serious like configuring a real server, in case it is hallucinating ;)

@AndrewMorton, I know. I'm seeking info to confirm what chatgpt is suggesting

@mortenma71 You can use IIS Crypto to check/set the TLS versions. You can't trust ChatGPT, at most you can use it as a source of suggestions that may or may not have any basis in reality, IMHO.

@AndrewMorton. do you have any ideas why IIS Crypto appears to show that tls12 is enabled, while the powershell code indicates tls12 is not enabled?

@mortenma71 Sorry, I have no idea about that. You could visit https://clienttest.ssllabs.com:8443/ssltest/viewMyClient.html with Internet Explorer on the server and see which protocols are enabled - if TLS 1.2 works there then it must be enabled in Server 2012.
