# Separating a part of the current URL

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want Separating a part of the current URL

> Example:localhost:50981/Admin/AddCustomer.aspx

The part I want: AddCustomer
or

> Example:localhost:50981/Request/Customer.aspx

The part I want: Customer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AbsolutePath` in your `onLoad` function of page.

```
//AddCustomer or Customer 
string yourPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Split('/').Last().Split('.')[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `string.Split()`:

```
var url = "localhost:50981/Admin/AddCustomer.aspx";
var result = url.Split('/').Last().Split('.')[0];
```

To get the current `Url` path in *Asp.Net*:

```
var url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
```

**Note**:
If you are interested in how to get the different parts of an url have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4195319/5453249) answer:

> ```
> var scheme = Request.Url.Scheme; // will get http, https, etc.
> var host = Request.Url.Host; // will get www.mywebsite.com
> var port = Request.Url.Port; // will get the port
> var path = Request.Url.AbsolutePath; // should get the /pages/page1.aspx part, can't remember if it only get pages/page1.aspx
> ```