# Extract left part of HTTP URI containing scheme, host and port (everything before the path)

Tags: powershell, uri

```
PS C:\Users\user> Split-Path "http://localhost:9200/index" -Parent
http:\\localhost:9200
```

In above example, I am trying to extract everything before the /index. I thought Split-Path would do the job but it changes the forward slashes in http:// to back  slashes.

```
"http://localhost:9200/index" -replace ([Uri]"http://localhost:9200/index").AbsolutePath
```

I've worked out the above alternative which works but Split-Path just seems cleaner. Just wondering why it does that with the forward slashes?

Comment: `Split-Path` is specifically for provider paths, not URI's in general. Try something like `$uri = [Uri]'http://localhost:9200/index'; '{0}://{1}{2}' -f $uri.Scheme,$uri.Authority,-join($uri.Segments|select -SkipLast 1)`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen `$uri.GetLeftPart('Authority')` is easier to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Split-Path` works with [provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_providers?view=powershell-7.2) paths only. Instead, use the .NET class [`Uri`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=net-6.0) that is specifically made for parsing URIs.

Using the method [`Uri.GetLeftPart()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.getleftpart?view=net-6.0), a partial URI can be extracted from the URI. This is much easier than building it "manually" by concatenating the URI components.

```sh
$uri = [uri] 'http://localhost:9200/index'
$uri.GetLeftPart('Authority')

# or as a one-liner:
([uri] 'http://localhost:9200/index').GetLeftPart('Authority')
```

**Output:**

```text
http://localhost:9200
```

---

By passing other values from the [UriPartial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uripartial?view=net-6.0) enum, different parts of the URI can be returned:

```sh
$uri = [uri] 'http://localhost:9200/index?param=value#anchor'

foreach( $part in 'Scheme','Authority','Path','Query' ) {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Part = $part
        URI  = $uri.GetLeftPart( $part )
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```text
Part      URI
----      ---
Scheme    http://
Authority http://localhost:9200
Path      http://localhost:9200/index
Query     http://localhost:9200/index?param=value
```

---

As noted by [this related C# answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/578083/7571258), there is one catch with `Uri.GetLeftPart()`:

If the port is the **default port** for the scheme, it will strip it out. E. g., the URI `http://localhost:80/index` gets turned into `http://localhost/index`, because port 80 is the default for the HTTP scheme.

If this is a problem, then you may use the [`UriBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uribuilder?view=net-6.0) class to manually build the new URI from the parts of the original URI, while avoiding direct string manipulation:

```sh
Function Get-UriBase( [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)] [Uri] $Uri ) {
    process {
        $uriBase = [UriBuilder]::new( $uri.Scheme, $uri.Host, $uri.Port ).ToString()
        # Output $uriBase if original URI starts with this part
        if( $uri.OriginalString.StartsWith( $uriBase ) ) { 
            return $uriBase 
        }
        # Otherwise original URI didn't contain a port, so use GetLeftPart() which omits it
        $uri.GetLeftPart('Authority')
    }
}

foreach( $uri in 'http://localhost:80/index', 'http://localhost:1234/index', 'http://localhost/index' ) {
    # For output in table format
    [PSCustomObject]@{ URI = $uri; URI_Base = Get-UriBase $uri }
}
```

**Output:**

```text
URI                         URI_Base
---                         --------
http://localhost:80/index   http://localhost:80/  
http://localhost:1234/index http://localhost:1234/
http://localhost/index      http://localhost
```

Comment: so what if I wanted not to omit the default port? although this is the best answer so far

Comment: @Yk84 Added a solution to include the default port.

Comment: @Yk84 I've created a function that outputs URL with port only, if original URL contained port.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `[uri]` type accelerator. Like so,

```
$u = [uri]"http://localhost:9200/index"
$u.LocalPath # Get the local path property
/index
```

Since accelerator creates an Uri obect, it works with more complex urls too. E.g.

```
$u = [uri]"http://localhost:9200/index/data.htm?foo=bar&qaz=zof"
$u # Print members, some omitted for brevity

AbsolutePath   : /index/data.htm
AbsoluteUri    : http://localhost:9200/index/data.htm?foo=bar&qaz=zof
LocalPath      : /index/data.htm
Authority      : localhost:9200
...
PathAndQuery   : /index/data.htm?foo=bar&qaz=zof
Segments       : {/, index/, data.htm}
IsUnc          : False
Host           : localhost
Port           : 9200
Query          : ?foo=bar&qaz=zof
...
OriginalString : http://localhost:9200/index/data.htm?foo=bar&qaz=zof
...
```

To get just the protocol and authority part, either search and replace, or join properties. Like so,

```
# -replace
$u.OriginalString -replace [regex]::escape($u.PathAndQuery), ''
http://localhost:9200

# build string
 "{0}://{1}:{2}" -f $u.scheme, $u.host, $u.port                 
http://localhost:9200
```

Comment: I require everything before the /index including the http:// so .LocalPath or .Authority wont cut it

Comment: @Yk84 See update

Answer (score 0):

Split-Path returns a specified part of a (file) path and in Windows the directories are separated using a backslash. If you run the same command on Linux, you will probably get the desired output.

The best way would probably be the [solution from Mathias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73608732/powershell-split-path-changes-forwards-slashes-to-back-slashes#comment129985293_73608732) (parse the URI and format the string). Another workaround with the `Split-Path` cmdlet would be to replace all backslashes with forward slashes:

```
(Split-Path "http://localhost:9200/index" -Parent) -replace '\\', '/'
```